# Is there a way to store certain shortcut variables in iTerm or Terminal.app so that we can access them from any remote machine ?

Tags: macos, terminal, iterm

I use alias for setting up shortcuts so that i need not type out often lengthy directory paths and such. But i ssh into multiple machines often and i cannot alias a bunch of stuff into all the remote machines. So is there a way to store global aliases in iTerm or Terminal ?

For example if want to type just 'dr' to take me to a directory /Users/xxx/yyy/sss etc. I use alias for this now but can i make it work in other remotes i log in to ?